# Cheap Hackable e-ink ebook reader

Tags: e-ink

I'm looking for a *seriously* cheap ebook reader that is hackable.

I want to turn it into a bed-side alarm clock.

Someone mentioned Onyx Boox, but there's 3 problems with them, (1) way too big, (2) they're not what I'd call cheap and (3) they have no stock anyway.

Comment: Try asking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What about an actual alarm clock? :)

Comment: Hey @kenorb Thanks for the recommendation, but this is more of a hardware recommendation than a software one.

Comment: Hey @Sekhemty, every alarm clock that I've every used has had LEDs as the digits, I've even used one that dims in the dark. However, no matter how dark the display gets, it's still bright enough to keep me awake. So the only other real option is to use a display that has no active lighting - hence e-ink displays. Unfortunately I can't just use a replacement e-ink display, as they need ASICs (application-specific integrated circuit). This is why I imagine that using an eBook reader would be able to accomplish this. Moot point now though as this has been deemed off-topic.